# Calculating percentile using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I Understand there are many answers saying how to calculate percentile using LINQ, but I could not find any relevant answer for my problem.

I have a list of object, which contains time duration as one of the properties on which I have to calculate the percentile by grouping the list by name. Is there any easiest way to do this using linq in C#. 
My object looks like below:

```
class Performance{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> DurationMilliSeconds { get; set; }
        public string typeName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What sort of answers have you found and why do they not apply to your question? Also, to clarify, you do mean [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile), right?

Comment: What [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) do you want ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Random r = new Random();
int performers = 500;
var performances = Enumerable.Range(1, performers)
  .Select(e => new Performance { Name="P"+e, DurationMilliSeconds=r.Next(5000)});
var pCount = performances.Count();
var percentiles = performances
  .OrderBy(p => p.DurationMilliSeconds)
  .Select((p, i) => new { p, i=i+1 })
  .Select(p => new {
    Name = p.p.Name,
    Duration = p.p.DurationMilliSeconds,
    Percentile = p.i / (decimal)pCount
  });
```

Comment: what happend if same DurationMilliSeconds is came in list

Comment: @NikhilVC what would that matter? If you need to order by name when that happens, you could simply add ThenBy().

Comment: it will always giving different percentile for same values

Comment: @NikhilVC,  I don't understand what you mean. Please post as a question with sample data showing what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

This will construct a dictionary that maps instances of `Performance`, grouped by name to the percentage of the sum of the group's `DurationMilliSeconds` property compared to the total duration of all `Performance` objects in the collection. Assumes `null` durations to be 0.

```
var performances = Enumerable.Empty<Performance>();
var totalDuration = performances.Sum(p => p.DurationMilliSeconds ?? 0M);
var durationPercentages = performances
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .ToDictionary(
        group => group.Key,
        group => group.Sum(p => (p.DurationMilliSeconds ?? 0M))/totalDuration);
```

Comment: Doesn't this give the percentage, rather than the percentile?

Comment: Hmm this is true, I assumed percentage was meant. I'll look into it